Simpleaudio causes a segmentation fault in Tkiinter
I am agnostic as to which solution I use, but in the following code, the simpleaudio solution outputs the sound, but causes a segmentation fault, whereas the pygame solution works perfectly.
Why is this?
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import simpleaudio as sa
from pygame import mixer

root = tk.Tk()


def main() -> None:
    MainFrame()
    root.mainloop()


class MainFrame():
    """Define the Main frame."""
    def __init__(self):
        button = ttk.Button(root, text='SimpleAudio', command=self.simple_audio)
        button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        button = ttk.Button(root, text='PyGame', command=self.pygame)
        button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def simple_audio(self):
        ping = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('ping.wav')
        play = ping.play()
        play.wait_done()

    def pygame(self):
        mixer.init()
        mixer.Sound("ping.wav").play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I am using
Python: 3.12.3
simpleaudio: 1.0 4
pygame: 2.5.2

probably the duplicate of this similar segmentation error question, check this out.
but out from that, have you tried to make sure the ping.wav file is present in the correct file path? maybe you should try to copy the relative file path into the argument.
or perhaps, try upgrading your simplaudio library as it could be a compatibility issue when running the program. let me know~

I am using the the same ping.wav in both implementations. I have only installed simpleaudio and pygame today - I have added  versions to my question
